# Adding zeros in between elements in numpy array with (a,b,c) shape

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array like this

```
array([[[1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]],

       [[1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]]])
```

shape = (2, 3, 5)

And I want an output which looks like this

```
output = array([[[1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1.],
         [1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1.],
         [1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1.]],

        [[1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1.],
         [1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1.],
         [1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1.]]])
```

Note: The number of zeros to be inserted can vary depending on given factor, in this case the factor was k=3, and the insert is (k-1) which means two zeros will be inserted between numbers. Also given this output I would like to get to the initial input

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`numpy.zeros`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html) to initialize an `output` array of the desired shape, then indexing to fill the values:

```
k = 3
shape = a.shape
output = np.zeros(shape[:-1]+((shape[-1]-1)*k+1,))

output[...,::k] = a
```

output:

```
array([[[1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1.],
        [1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1.],
        [1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1.]],

       [[1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1.],
        [1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1.],
        [1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1.]]])
```